# Set CivCRM Email to Blank by REST API

Tags: rest, civicrm

I am trying to set the email address to blank in CiviCRM. I serialise an array as below and post via REST (code is groovy):

```
def rest = [
                json: 1,
                api_key: apiKey,
                key: siteKey,
                debug: 1,
                version: 3,
                entity: 'Contact',
                action: 'create',
                contact_type: contact_type,
                overwriteblank:true,
                id: record.crID,
                rest["email[1][email]"] = modified.value as String
                rest["email[1][location_type_id]"] = 1
        ]
```

I have tried the 'overwriteblank' option - but the email still does not seem to be set to blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An email address is a separate API entity from the contact (since a contact can have an infinite number of email addresses).  All you need to do is get the email entries where the contact_id = whatever and then delete them.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Email', 'get', array('contact_id' => $YOUR_CONTACT_ID));
```

then after checking for errors and iterating over $result['values']:

```
$deleted = civicrm_api3('Email', 'delete', array('id' => $YOURRESULTROW['id']));
```

With the SQL method, you're not deleting the email so much as setting that person's email to be an empty string.

Comment: Those are PHP API calls, but the equivalent should work for your REST method.

Comment: REST as per entity=Email&id=33&action=delete&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&api_key={yoursitekey}&key={yourkey}

Answer (score -1):

The best that I could do was by sql.

```
String sql_update = """update civicrm_email set email = "" where contact_id = ?"""
```

Comment: This means that you're saving the email record to be an empty string.  Ultimately, you want to delete the email record so it's clear that the contact has no email.

Comment: The email was set to blank not deleted in the source system so was deliberate. As to whether for the best operation of civicrm or not is a good question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Interlated, generally CiviCRM tries not to store blank emails. On another point though, I'm wondering if you would be willing to help us launch a new StackExchange site for CiviCRM at ttp://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm -- we have lots of people interested, but we need another 36 people with 200+ reputation on another StackExchange site to commit before we can launch. Would you help us out? Thanks!

Comment: @Joe - yes I know . It is a silly hack to synchronise data - web service/messaging make data source a like data source b project. Yes I voted for your proposal - looks good.